# Scripting tasks in eclipse and calling from CrusieControl

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, cruisecontrol

I am relatively new to Eclipse and Java and have a number of tasks I would like to script when I am going to do a software release. They include running JAXB to generate source from an XSD, running javadoc to update the documentation and creating jars for distribution. What is the best way of scripting these tasks...Ant? I need the scripts to be called from our nightly build environment which is CrusieControl.net. We use both C# and Java in house but we have a single build environment on CruiseControl.net

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at here :

1. [How to execute the JAXB compiler from ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630474/how-to-execute-the-jaxb-compiler-from-ant)
2. [Javadoc task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)
3. [Run ant from cc.net](http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/Using%20CruiseControl.NET%20with%20Ant.html)

I'll say go for it. We have a similar environment without java, but with tones of tools. Ant is a very useful weapon in your arsenal.