# Generating java classes via jaxb and ant against xsd

Tags: java, ant, jaxb

I have a module with some structure (src/com/mycompany). I need to generate part of code from xsd using jaxb. Also it's important to  generate them on building stage.  I need specify ant target for it.

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
<classpath path="${xjc.task.path}"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="schema-to-java">
<xjc destdir="./src/gen">
<schema dir="./META-INF/xsd" includes="**/*.xsd"/>
</xjc>
</target>
```

xjc.task.path - path to jaxb-2.0 directory.

src and META-INF are located on the same level (project dir)

Project builds successfully but no classes are generated

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630474/how-to-execute-the-jaxb-compiler-from-ant

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't have classes generated is because you don't **compile your java source codes (i.e. .java)**.

**xjc** ant ask will just generate java source code. You need another ant task for generating classes which is the **javac**